# How do you use the Venti Calendar plugin with the Element API plugin?

Tags: plugin-elementapi, plugin-ventievents

I want an endpoint in the [Element API plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) that shows the last event entries from the [Venti Calendar](https://venticalendar.io) plugin. The Element API guide tells that's possible to use the plugin with custom element types. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the Venti Calendar plugin, so I can't test this, but it should be as simple as setting the `elementType` propety to whatever custom element type the plugin has created and you want to use and (optionally) setting any criteria you want defined by the element type.

```
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'news.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Venti_Event',
            'criteria' => ['key' => 'value'], 
            'transformer' => function(Venti_EventModel $eventModel) {
                return [
                    'key' => $eventModel->property,
                ];
            },
        },
    ]
];
```

Comment: The custom element type is "Venti_Event".

Comment: Cool... I assume there is a `Venti_EventModel` as well?

Comment: Yes that would be it Venti_EventModel

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: I tried it with 'Venti_EventElementType' as elementType name after searching in the plugin files that was the problem ;) thanx for the answer!